# Python Pyramid Character Printing error

Tags: python

I am trying to have the user select what character will be used to construct the pyramid

```
sizePy=int(input('Enter number of lines: '))
charPy = raw_input("Enter the character: ")

for i in range(1,sizePy+1):
    print ((sizePy-i)*' '+i*"%s " %charPy)
```

Comment: You say you're getting an error... but what is the error message? Please include it in your question.

Comment: The error is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by the following:

```
i*"%s " %charPy
```

After applying the `*` operator, for example if i is 5, this would be:

```
"%s %s %s %s %s " %charPy
```

and you only have one `charPy` and 5 `%s`. To fix this, change it to:

```
i*("%s " %charPy)
```

where Python will do the `charPy` substitution first, and then repeat that string `i` times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Python3`, the following may work

```
sizePy=int(input('Enter number of lines: '))
charPy = input("Enter the character: ")

for i in range(1,sizePy+1):
    print ((sizePy-i)*' '+i*"{0}".format(charPy))
```